# How do i create seperate tasks for every objects with celery beat in Django models

Tags: django, django-models, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

### Let's assume we have following model field:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    project_scan = models.IntegerField()  ### Scan interval
    project_status = models.BooleanField() ### To Enable "Scan" or Disable "Scan" Tasks
```

### Assume We have 2 Project Objects:

```
1. Project(project_name='test1',project_scan=5) ### Scan `test1` every `5` hour
2. Project(project_name='test2',project_scan=10) ### Scan `test2` every `10` hour
```

### Tasks.py

```
@task(name='project_tasks')
def Project_Tasks():
    get_all_projects = Project.objects.all()
    for each_project in get_all_project:
        if each_project.project_status == True: ### Checking if it "Scan" is allowed.
            get_interval = each_project.project_scan
            get_name = each_project.project_name
            print(get_name)
```

My Question : 
How do i run tasks on each object based on given `project_scan` Interval ? , Since Celery beat takes Tasks name as argument to perform scan like:
`PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=given_interval, name='I dont know', task='project_tasks', )`

How do i create separate instance for each project task ?

I Tried creating intervalSchedule field in models.py but didn't worked:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    project_scan = models.IntegerField()  ### Scan interval
    project_status = models.BooleanField() ### To Enable "Scan" or Disable "Scan" Tasks
    schedule = IntervalSchedule()
```

Comment: Do you want for `PeriodTask` to be created when a new `Project` is created? Oh you what to run it during for cycle?

Comment: Yes,PeriodicTask to be created when a new project is created and run a cycle based on given interval time i.e `project_scan (hour)`

Comment: See my answer below. If you have questions, please leave your comment under it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add use signals:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule


class Project(models.Model):
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    project_scan = models.IntegerField()  
    project_status = models.BooleanField()


    def set_periodic_task(self, task_name):
        schedule = self.get_or_create_interval()
        PeriodicTask.objects.create(
            interval=schedule, 
            name=f'{self.project_name}-{self.id}', 
            task=task_name,
        )

    def get_or_create_interval(self):
        schedule, created = IntervalSchedule.objects.get_or_create(
            every=self.project_scan,
            period=IntervalSchedule.HOURS,
        )
        return schedule

    def get_periodic_task(self, task_name):
        interval = self.get_or_create_interval()
        periodic_task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(
            interval=interval, 
            name=f'{self.project_name}-{self.id}', 
            task=task_name,
        )
        return periodic_task

    def sync_disable_enable_task(self, task_name):
        periodic_task = self.get_periodic_task(task_name)
        periodic_task.enabled = self.project_status
        periodic_task.save()


@receiver(post_save, sender=Project)
def set_or_sync_periodic_task(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.set_periodic_task(task_name='project_tasks')
    else:
        instance.sync_disable_enable_task(task_name='project_tasks')
```

What you have there:
When you created a new `Project` instance a new Periodic task is saved with method `set_periodic_task`. If you want to `disable` or `enable` periodic task of your instance you just change `project_status` status and save it. It will trigger `sync_disable_enable_task` method for enabling or disabling.

if you want to pass args you can do:

```
 PeriodicTask.objects.create(
     interval=schedule,
     name=f'{self.project_name}-{self.id}', 
     task='proj.tasks.import_contacts',
     args=json.dumps(['arg1', 'arg2']),
     kwargs=json.dumps({
        'some_kwarg': '123,
     }),
)
```

Comment: I Guess that might be because i'm iterating objects from `tasks.py` and printing it out.

Comment: What do you want to do in `Project_Tasks` task? You are getting all `Project`s and printing them,

Comment: is there any way to pass argument to our `Project_Tasks` function in tasks.py? to run that particular object only, Based on current task, ex: https://pastebin.com/raw/ss7a8VWB

Comment: Hello Sergey,  This is creating a `celery.backend_cleanup` a task in Periodic Tasks with the default which is set to `4 hour each interval`, thread at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53958965/question-usage-of-django-celery-backend-cleanup