# Question: Usage of django celery.backend_cleanup

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task, celerybeat

There is not much documentation available for the actual usage of `django celery.backend_cleanup`

Let's assume i have following `4 tasks scheduled with different interval`

[image]

Checking DatabaseScheduler Logs I had found that only `Task1` is executing on interval.

```
[2018-12-28 11:21:08,241: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:24:08,778: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:27:09,315: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:28:32,948: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Scheduler: Sending due TASK1(project_monitor_tasks)
[2018-12-28 11:30:13,215: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:33:13,772: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:36:14,316: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:39:14,868: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:42:15,397: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:43:55,700: INFO/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
[2018-12-28 11:43:55,700: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 11:45:15,997: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
.....
....
[2018-12-28 17:16:28,613: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:19:29,138: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:22:29,625: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:25:30,140: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:28:30,657: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:28:32,943: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due TASK1(project_monitor_tasks)
[2018-12-28 17:31:33,441: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:34:34,009: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:37:34,578: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:40:35,130: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:43:35,657: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:43:50,716: INFO/MainProcess] DatabaseScheduler: Schedule changed.
[2018-12-28 17:43:50,716: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:46:36,266: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:49:36,809: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
[2018-12-28 17:52:37,352: INFO/MainProcess] Writing entries...
```

Q1) why other `TASKS` which are at different intervals such as `24,8,10` Hours are not executing? , I'm Assuming this is because  `Crontab of  celery.backend_cleanup` is set to every `4 Hours` which is cleaning up queue tasks. Should i keep the large interval time for `celery.backend_cleanup` task ?

Q2) Why we should keep `celery.backend_cleanup` task?  Does it loads new tasks on every cleanup?

Comment: Same Author, Same Issues. Just better answer explanation [djang-celery-beat issues #213](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/213)

Answer (score 3):

Q1:  We can't answer more without seeing the actual schedules, knowing your configuration of celery, or the logs past twenty-four hours.  The `backend_cleanup` job has no effect on the broker, it's purpose is to clean up task results that have expired by deleting expired results from an RDBMS celery result backend, so it would have no effect on whether a task executes properly.

Q2:  See above.  You should use this task if you are using an RDBMS / database backend if you want your expired celery results to be deleted from your celery results backend database.